# How to remap fast up and down (ctrl u and ctrl d) to ctrl j and ctrl k in Vim

Tags: vim

How can I remap the fast up and down commands?
I would like to remap <kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>?

I tried the following but no luck...

```
nnoremap <c-u> <c-k> 
nnoremap <c-d> <c-j>
```

FYI - Vim is installed in Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key presses should go in the opposite order:

```
nnoremap <C-k> <C-u>
nnoremap <C-j> <C-d>
```

Comment: You are right there is a syntax error. I changed it and still doesn't work. Weird but it works within Vim temporary but not when added to the .vimrc file.

Comment: When you load vim (relying on vimrc to perform the mapping) and type :nmap can you see the mappings you're after?

Comment: I created ~/.vimrc as a new file with only these two lines and it worked.

Comment: Found the issue, the mapping `<C-k>` and `<C-j>`  were already assigned for other commands. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: This was helpful for me trying to remap `<C-r>` for redo (`noremap  U <C-r>` for redo, if anyone cares). I was using completely the wrong syntax.